# Functional weekly workout routine

Tags: workout-routines, workout, bodyweight-exercises, stamina, functional-strength

I want to to find or create a weekly workout routine.
I'm not interested to become muscular.
I don't want to spend money (for example gym or equipment).
I don't like running only workouts.

I want to workout no more than 3 days per week and no more than 30 minutes per workout.

I have a pullup bar and an 8 kg kettlebell (maybe not heavy enough for me).

My goals:

- to perform 50 pushups in a row (now I can do only 15 in a row)
- to perform 10 pull ups (I can't do any pull up)
- to have enough stamina to complete easily a football (soccer) match
- to have fullbody functional fitness

I'm male 29 years old 180 cm heigh , 85 kg.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would argue that if you only train 30 minutes at a time, a 90 minutes soccer game will hardly ever be easy. For your other 3 goals, have you tried googling "full body bodyweight workout"? Bodyweight training is very hip at the moment, you will find a lot of resources online

Comment: Thanks for the response! I ve found on internet workout routines for full bodyweigh workout, but I want to find a way to combine in a workout full bodyweight and stamina training. As for soccer I' m not playing proffesionally, but in amateur level (I don't play in a soccer club, but I play occasionally matches that usually last 1 hour without break)

Comment: To me it seems as if you have a clear picture of what such a workout should look like - or else you would just do the obvious and some bodyweight stuff and then some cardio. Could you include a description of what exactly you are looking for? It's great that you've included your goals, but I don't see why google didn't just give you the answer as you suggest

Comment: you have to quantify "fullbody functional fitness"

Comment: Just do “The Murph.” You work up to it in stages, of course, but it’s a 1 mile run, then 300 air squats, 200 pushups, and 100 pull-ups, then another 1 mile run. Oh and you wear a 20-lb vest as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fitness, you achieve results faster by focusing on one goal at a time.  you wouldnt learn muay thai. boxing, kung fu, karate, and judo simultaneously right?
Work on your stamina first it will carry over into your future workouts..
You need to build all 3 energy systems,  alactic, lactic. and aerobic.Thisll get you ready for a 90 min game.

alactic- do 3-7 sets of 10 sprints about 100 meters. add distance and sets over time.

lactic- do bodyweight workouts lasting 50-70 seconds

aerobic-sorry but if you dont want to jog you need to swim or at the least do a metcon workout day.

Next,
Build up pushups and functional workout
-simply shoot for adding a rep each week. Now that your energy system is better youll have more stamina.youll also be able to do more from your functional workout(see below)

unless you want to invest in a cheap set of bands, resistance bands, or that thin elastic band people use(all these are like 30 bucks for multiple sets! great deal) than use bodyweight full body workouts 3x a week

For a few weeks.. do one full body workout, then 2 workouts with extra chest exercises and less of everything else

Then do the same but with back exercises. this will help your pull ups in the long run. lots of latpulls and horizontal rows then do pull up negatives.

Now with your limited 30 minute window you may have to  focus on 1 full body workout day that's 60 minutes and then do 2 30 minute workouts later that week. 30 minutes is not a lot for your goals unless you have a lot of time to slowly progress. Make sure your diet is in check too.. muscles or not.. you need them for pullups(you need back muscles to do this as well as strength) and muscular endurance so get ready to gain a little.

Answer (score 1):

If I look at your current stats I think the main thing you want to do is lose some weight and build some strength. This will allow you to do more pushups and pullups.

Also, if you want to be able to do a soccer match, you'll want to do high intensity interval training (HIIT). During a soccer match you're doing a lot of short sprints and efforts of jumping etc.

I think a crossfit type of training would suit your goals. It will help you build some strength for those pushups and pullups, if will provide some HIIT to become better at doing those soccer matches, and at the same time you'll probably lose some weight (if you're not just stuffing your face with food all day).

You can do crossfit workouts at home if you don't want to spend any money, simply by looking them up on the internet and working with the stuff you have. The pullup bar and kettlebell will bring you a long way. Once it becomes too easy a simple thing to do is fill some empty bottles and put them in a backpack. This way you'll add extra resistance to what ever you're doing.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! Is it better to go for 3 hiit training per week containing bodyweight excercises or to do bodyweight strength workouts and after each workout add a tabata session (8 sets in a row, each set consists of 20 sec excersise and 10 sec break)? I ve read a lot about tabata on internet but I' m confused about its efficiency. I tried yesterday to do a tabata workout including only jumping jacks (8 sets of 20 sec excersise and 10 sec break) in my highest intensity ( about 24 jumping jacks per 20 sec) and I found it easy, in the end I didn't sweat , but today my shoulder muscles are sore !

Answer (score 1):

I think that in order to do 50 push ups you need to both increase your strength and endurance.
You can already do 15 pushups. That means that push ups are too light to increase your strength. They will only increase your endurance.
Right now you can probably bench press roughly 3/4 of your bodyweight.
You should increase this to roughly 1 x bodyweight. The best way to do this would be to actually do bench press but with a narrow grip. If not you could try doing push ups with some books in a backpack on your back.  You could also use narrow grip and clapping push ups. You should alternate between heavy days where you only do 5-8 reps and light days where you do as many ordinary push ups as possible.

You can see this described better here:
[ZERO TO 100 PUSHUPS](http://scoobysworkshop.com/zero-to-100-pushups-for-complete-beginners/)
You are in phase 4.

Regarding the pull ups. You should do 3 set of 5-8 incline pull ups. And finish off with one set of 5 negatives; that is you use a chair to get up on the bar an then lower yourself slowly.